# getting a substring of a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have this kind of string

Lastname, FirstName MiddleName

I would like them to be put in 3 different textboxes

FirstName
MiddleName
LastName

but i cant seem to get it right,

I have these code for my project:

```
Name = Me.dtgEmplist.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value

fname = Name.Substring(Name.IndexOf(" ")).Trim
mname = fname.Substring(fname.IndexOf(" ")).Trim
lname = Name.Substring(0, Name.IndexOf(",")).Trim
```

I seem to get the LastName and middlenames correctly, but the firstname is very tricky, I only succeed in getting this kind of output

FirstName MiddleName
MiddleName
LastName

could someone help me out? I've been trying this out for so long.

EDIT: they are taken from a datagridview. And the datagridview view is populated from a stored procedure

Comment: Hi please tell me which type of string comes in the Name = Me.dtgEmplist.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value

Comment: @ChetanSanghani sir, the string with "Name" produces is "Lastname, FirstName MiddleName" which is taken from a column of a datagrid sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easy if you use Split method as the others said:

```
Name = Me.dtgEmplist.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value

Dim FirstSplit as String()
FirstSplit = Name.Split(",")
fname = FirstSplit(0).Trim()

Dim SecondSplit as String() = (FirstSplit(1).Trim()).Split()

mname = SecondSplit(0).Trim
lname = SecondSplit(1).Trim
```

First of all you split for the ',' character and then you split for the space. Maybe you also should check for array dimension.

Comment: This worked sir! but somehow, there are middle Names that has spaces

i.e Smith, James De Castro and the "Castro" gets ignored, i'll just fix this myself, but thanks for the start!

Comment: This is a more complicated problem. How can you distinguish between a space between FistsName and MiddleName and a space inside the name? You should use another escape character.

Comment: I somehow used SecondSplit.length and captured how many spaces are there in the name, i just hope that there isnt a firstname with 2 spaces or this would get way off

Comment: I think that it is not deterministic, you should separate the names using another escape char.

Comment: probably, because there are names that has 2 first names or 2 middle names, i would have to change to process of retrieving the string to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier with string.Split(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

you can first split whole string on coma:

```
string[] splitted
string[] splitted2
splitted = Name.Split(New Char() {","c})

fName = splitted(0).Trim
splitted2  = splitted(1).Split(New Char() {" "c}

mname = splitted2(0).Trim()
lname = splitted2(1).Trim()
```

Comment: Sir, do you have anything that is VB.net?

Comment: It doesn't look like Vb.net. It is an hybrid.

Comment: Sorry for that, haven't use VB.NET for many years. I haven't tried to build this code.